# R this.path does not return the correct output if source in customized function on start

Tags: r

When starting RStudio, I use the `R/R-4.3.2/etc/Rprofile.site` to source custom functions written by myself. One of the customized functions uses `this.path` to access the directory of whatever specific R file, which is calling the customized function with `this.path`.

So I have a function `RelPath()` sourced on start, calling it in Script.R, RelPath() does not return the path from Script.R but that of RelPath. This strange behaviour only appears when RelPath() is sourced from on start, not when I source it manually.

Probably a rooky mistake, but I cannot resolve it from related questions.

Rprofile.site contains one single line of code:

```
source("D:/.../OnStart.R")
```

OnStart.R

```
RelPath = function(MoveUpLevels = 1, Subdir){  
  Path = this.path::this.path()
  # Move up x levels towards root directory to access directories of current R file
  MoveUpLevels = MoveUpLevels + 1
  if(MoveUpLevels > 0){
    for(i in 1:MoveUpLevels){
      Path = sub("/[^/]+$", "", Path)
    }
  }
  # If sub directory is given, then check if it is exists
  # If so, then add, else throw warning
  if(!missing(Subdir)){
    if(file.exists(file.path(Path,Subdir))){
      Path=file.path(Path,Subdir)
    }else{
      warning(paste0("Given subdirectory is not found on system: ", file.path(Path,Subdir)))
    }
  }
  return(Path)
}
```

Script.R

```
RelPath(0)
> "D:/.../OnStart.R"
```

I would have expected output: "E:/.../Script.R"

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood the question. I’m not entirely sure how to fix this but I think you might need to play with the `n` argument to `this.path()`.

Comment: I think the solution would be just to avoid sourcing any functions on start but move to libraries which are sourced at start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of `package:this.path`.

`this.path()` returns the path of the script in which it is written, which is not what you want. You could instead use `sys.path()` which returns the path of the executing script. To demonstrate this, try running `example("sys.path")`.

This was a change I made in **this.path 2.0.0** because of this issue: https://github.com/ArcadeAntics/this.path/issues/13

You could also refer to `news(package = "this.path")` specifically section `Changes in version 2.0.0` subsection `Significant User-Visible Changes` where I explain why I made those changes.

Sorry for the confusion. If you have any suggestions for how I can improve the documentation to make it easier for other users to understand, that'd be great, thank you!

One more thing, @Konrad Rudolph mentioned using argument `n` to `this.path()`. That is another option, though I will have a hard time explaining it concisely here. You can refer to section `Argument 'n'` of `?this.path` if you'd like to see how to use it.

Comment: Returning the path of the executing script makes a lot of sense for working with relative paths. Though, if I want to make a customized script out of this.path, I would need another script in the middle, which contains the call to this.path and then technically becomes the executing script. So if I call now from my script my customized function using this.path, I will not get the path to my current project but the path to wherever I have my customized function calling this.path.

Comment: Furthermore, sourcing the customized function manually, the behaviour changes. That means, sourced on start, the customized function will return the path of the customized function. Sourcing it manually, the customized function will return the path of the script from wherever the customized function was called.
That makes it suspiscious and thats why I opened the thread.
The use of the parameter "n" does not have an influence on these tests - it doesnt change anything.

Comment: I'm assuming what you mean is that behaviour is different when the function source()-ed i.e. source("D:/.../OnStart.R") vs is created in the R Console, i.e. run keyboard shortcut, run button, or copy-pasted. That's because a source()-ed function will have a srcref referring to a file, while one created in the R Console will not refer to a file. I think you should read through ?this.path and ?sys.path, they explain it far better than I can with this limited number of characters.